# MVC - Bootstrap 3.0 - Change navbar text

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, navbar

I am having trouble changing the color of my text in the navbar I'm using, and this is my current layout code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:#61B00D;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand"  })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

and the style:background-color in my top div in my body is working fine, but when I add color:white behind it, it doesn't affect the text in my navbar, it just remains this weird blue-ish color.

I've tried going into my custom css file (teststylesheet.css) and done:

```
.nav.navbar-nav li {
    background-color:#61B00D; color:crimson
}
```

but nothing happened. I'll admit I'm a rookie at CSS and HTML, and I feel like I'm doing something very obvious, very wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Tried adding the tip below to my stylesheet.css, but nothing happened.

Comment: Please post relevant HTML and CSS in your question.

Comment: The image attached shows the relevant HTML code, and my attempted CSS is written in the OP. Not sure what else I should add.

Comment: The html of the navbar and the css of all the elements within the nav. Posting images or codes in external links is not accepted here as they may expire thus rendering the thread useless for other people having this same issue in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the text in your navbar are links, you have to target the anchor links like this:

```
.nav li a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: tried adding your suggestion to my css stylesheet, but it didn't change the text color.

Comment: Try the above edited code snippet. You forgot to add spaces between the classes.

Comment: Tried the update code too, nothing happened unfortunately. As for adding all the css of the nav, there is none, except for the standard bootstrap 3.0 sheet.

Comment: I cloned your above code along with my code snippet in jsfiddle and it seems to be working fine though Fross. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/e0d8my79/202/

Comment: After fiddling around and watching a few youtube videos, I figured out I had misspelled something in my HTML. The above code snippet works, thanks!